# Handling multiple URL values in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm developing a site using the CakePHP framework. I have a form which shows a list of entities, with a tickbox for each one allowing you to select it. You then press a button at the bottom of the form saying "Edit selected".

My usual approach is to give each checkbox input the same name (e.g. `row_id`) and use the primary ID as the input's `value`. However, when you submit the form, CakePHP only seems to return *one* of the checkbox's values to the controller in `$this->params['url']`, rather than any kind of list like I'd expect.

Any tips on the right way to handle this, so that I can find out which rows were ticked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the FormHelper, the easiest way is to create your fields like this:

```
echo $form->input('ModelName.0.row_id', /* snip */)
echo $form->input('ModelName.1.row_id', /* snip */)
```

Etc.. you get the point. If it's a dynamic list, there always the `for` loop.

When the form is POSTed, this should give you a server side array like this ($this->data):

```
array
(
    ['ModelName'] => array
    (
        [0] => array
        (
            [row_id] => value
        ),
        [1] => array
        (
            [row_id] => value
        )
    )
)
```

Then you can use the Set utility class to extract your IDs (and mess with your data:))